# These theorems are equivalent (spectral theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know if these theorems are equivalent:

[image]

[image]

If the answer is yes, why the second one is more known as spectral theorem than the first one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are indeed the same, and they say the "exact" same thing in different ways. The second one however write out the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues so I guess thats why he/she choose to call it the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: @jeb I didn't understand the motivation of this name, what's a spectrum?

Comment: Think of it as Eigenvalues